# Facebook app in Development Mode returns no results

Tags: facebook-graph-api

According to the Facebook Graph API [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2019/09/23/live-mode-for-production-use/), apps in Development Mode have permission to call *any endpoint* for users that are registered Testers with the app. This is my situation. I am calling `/me/feed` for such a user. However, all that is returned is `{"data":[]}`. Shouldn't I be able to see the Tester's feed with this call?

Comment: Depends, on whether you got their permission first.

Comment: @CBroe If I add the users to my app's Testers group (in FB Dashboard, under Roels), and if they agree to the email they receieve, doesn't that in itself square away all the permissions? In other words, the app is in Dev Mode and the users have granted permission to the app to have them as Testers, so shouldn't the app at that point have permission to access the Tester's feed, etc?

Comment: No. It made them able to _access_ your app, while it is still in dev mode, but that is all. You still need to _ask_ them for the necessary permissions for whatever specific action(s) you want to perform via API.

Comment: I see now what you are referring to. There is a "scope" parameter (supplied during authtication) that contains an array of permssions for the user to grant to the app.